# pidstat command in android?

Tags: android, linux, arm, archlinux, busybox

Is there any substitute for `pidstat` command between the supported commands in `busybox`? I need to run `pidstat` on my Android device. I have `busybox` but `pidstat` is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busybox has no such command. It does however provide the `top` command which can be used in a similar fashion.

> top
>
> top [-b] [-nCOUNT] [-dSECONDS] [-m]
>
> Provide a view of process activity in real time. Read the status of all processes from `/proc` each SECONDS and display a screenful of them.

Where:

```
$ top -bn10 -p1
```

- `-b` - shows top in batch mode
- `n10` - shows 10 iterations and then stops
- `-p1` - shows PID 1

#### Example

```
$ top -bn10 -p1
top - 23:19:27 up  5:30,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1015500 total,   414600 free,    88176 used,   512724 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  2097148 free,        0 used.   737992 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0  125776   4240   2616 S  0.0  0.4   0:04.59 systemd
```

You can then use `grep` to filter this output like so:

```
$ top -bn10 -p1 | grep -A1 "PID"
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0  125776   4240   2616 S  0.0  0.4   0:04.61 systemd
--
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0  125776   4240   2616 S  0.0  0.4   0:04.61 systemd
--
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0  125776   4240   2616 S  0.0  0.4   0:04.61 systemd
--
```

You can of course manipulate `top` so that it shows a similar set of columns to what `pidstat` shows.